# Get font glyph index by character

Tags: c#, .net-core, gdi+

In `gdi.dll` we have [`GetGlyphIndices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144890(v=vs.85).aspx) function what translates a string into an array of glyph indices

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
internal static extern uint GetGlyphIndices(IntPtr hdc, string lpstr, int c, [In, Out] ushort[] pgi, uint fl);
...
string value = "ABCDEFG";
int count = value.Length;

ushort[] indexes = new ushort[count];

GetGlyphIndices(hdc, value , count, indexes, 1);
```

Now i'm porting my application to Net Core and there is no way to do same things.
I also view [libgdiplus](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/src/font.h) functions.

How can i get fonts glyph list in Net Core application? Maybe i missed it in GDI+?

Comment: So what do you need glyph indices for, absent *other* low-level font functions that can use them? You may be able to get somewhere with [FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) ([SharpFont](https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont) has .NET bindings for it). Disclaimer: never used either myself.

Comment: In my case glyph indexies retrivied by this function used to generate PDF files.